# How to add some number of months to a given date using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add months to a given date and want to output that date.

I am using this code, but it is not working.

```
    var p = '2015-10-21';
    var myDate = new Date(p);
    var result1 = myDate.addMonths(3);
```

I want the result to be: 2016-01-21

Comment: Date object doesn't have a method called addMonths

Comment: Please check your browser console for error debug

Comment: `.addMonths()` is in the datejs library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment library is awesome for date related functions.
You can do operations like add, subtract, etc. 
It has a syntax which is easily understandable.u can also avoid edge cases

If you included the moment library, your code could be rewritten like this

```
var p = '2015-10-21';
var myDate = moment(p, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
var result1 = myDate.add(3, 'months');
console.log (result1.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

You can learn about or download moment from: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You want to getMonth/setMonth

```
var p = '2015-10-21';
var myDate = new Date(p);
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 3);
```

Don't  worry about overflow - Date object handles it

Note. This overwrites myDate, if you want the result in a different var

```
var p = '2015-10-21';
var myDate = new Date(p);
var result1 = new Date(myDate);
result1.setMonth(result1.getMonth() + 3);
```

> as noted by @JohnHascall in the comments, this isn't fool proof around the end of month, for example adding three months to 30 November 2015 will result in 1st March 2016

Comment: Be careful around the end of months.  For example: adding 3 months to the last day of November gives March 1st -- which may or may not be what you are expecting.

Comment: @JohnHascall Good point - I'll add that warning to the answer for completeness - does any library handle such cases, and what SHOULD be the result in such cases (guess that's a matter of opinion)

Comment: I think most date libraries would adjust that to the last day of the month.  But as you say, what is 'right' is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
<script>
   var date = new Date();
   var month = date.getMonth()+1;
   var year = date.getFullYear();
   var day = date.getDate();

   function addMonth(addMonth){
     var u_date,u_year,u_month;
     u_date = month + addMonth;
     if(u_date > 12){
       var div = Math.floor(u_date / 12);
       var rem = u_date % 12;
       u_year = year + div;
       u_month = month + rem;
       document.getElementById("updated_date").innerHTML = day +" "+  u_month + " " + u_year;
     }else{
        document.getElementById("updated_date").innerHTML = day +" "+ (month+addMonth) + " " + year;
  }
}

addMonth(13);


</script>
```

Here is the html-

```
<div id="updated_date"></div>
```